# Where can I buy an Emperor ETR1 car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Lately, I am playing a lot of GTA Online. I have the vehicle export business, with which I get enough money. In one of the missions of that business, one day I had to sell a high-end car called 'Emperor ETR1'.

I liked the car a lot, and I was looking to see if it can be bought, but I didn't find it.

Could someone tell me if it is possible to buy that car? And if so, where can I get it, and how much does it cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wiki page](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/ETR1) says the car is available for purchase from Legendary Motorsports for $1,995,000.  The  vehicle was apart of the [Cunning Stunts](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/GTA_Online:_Cunning_Stunts) update.

Comment: Okey! I didn't see it my bad, thanks for your answer!